# OpenFileDialog in a dynamic QDialog

Tags: qt

I am trying to build a form with several LineEdits and I need an OpenFileDialog to select a Path and write it into one of the LineEdits.
The problem is, this form is generated "dynamically".
All of this needs to happen inside a function call, in which the Dialog and all LineEdits are created, so i can't just add a Button, link the clicked Signal to a new Slot, open the File Dialog in the Slot and write the result into the LineEdit.

Here is my Code from inside the function:

```
QDialog dialog(this);

QFormLayout form(&dialog);

QList<QLineEdit *> fields;

QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(&dialog);
QString label = QString("Name");
form.addRow(label, lineEdit);
fields << lineEdit;

lineEdit = new QLineEdit(&dialog);
label = QString("Time");
form.addRow(label, lineEdit);
fields << lineEdit;

lineEdit = new QLineEdit(&dialog);
label = QString("Number #1");
form.addRow(label, lineEdit);
fields << lineEdit;

lineEdit = new QLineEdit(&dialog);
label = QString("Number #2");
form.addRow(label, lineEdit);
fields << lineEdit;

lineEdit = new QLineEdit(&dialog);
label = QString("Number #3");
form.addRow(label, lineEdit);
fields << lineEdit;

//--------------Here should be the path selection
lineEdit = new QLineEdit(&dialog);
label = QString("Path");
form.addRow(label, lineEdit);
fields << lineEdit;
//-----------------------------------------------
QDialogButtonBox buttonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel,Qt::Horizontal, &dialog);
form.addRow(&buttonBox);
QObject::connect(&buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), &dialog, SLOT(accept()));
QObject::connect(&buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), &dialog, SLOT(reject()));

if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
//...Do stuff with the Text from the Line Edits
```

Is there a way to do this without making things global, so a Slot could access it?
Because I really like the idea of this form completely staying inside the function call.

Comment: Well, you can use lambda-functions connected to button clicks... But I would rather inherit from the QDialog and keep all the shenanigans inside the inherited class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the issue correctly, I think you need to redesign the application.

You need some variables in your class and update the dialog when the user changes the `QLineEdit` path. But to do this, you need the dialog as a member variable.

The next code is just an example, but it's a good way of showing you a way of solving this. Of course, there are many different options to do it.

Note #1: I don't know when you launch the dialog, so I've created a very basic ui with a button to display it.

**mainwindow.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>160</x>
      <y>120</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLineEdit>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void updateValues(const QString & text);
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QLineEdit* path;
    QLineEdit* name;
    QLineEdit* time;
    QLineEdit* number;
    QDialog* dialog;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDialog>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QDialogButtonBox>
#include <QFormLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    dialog = new QDialog(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFormLayout form(dialog);

    name = new QLineEdit(dialog);
    QString label = QString("Name");
    form.addRow(label, name);

    time = new QLineEdit(dialog);
    label = QString("Time");
    form.addRow(label, time);

    number = new QLineEdit(dialog);
    label = QString("Number #1");
    form.addRow(label, number);

    path = new QLineEdit(dialog);
    label = QString("Path");
    form.addRow(label, path);

    connect(path, &QLineEdit::textChanged,
     this, &MainWindow::updateValues );

    QDialogButtonBox buttonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel,Qt::Horizontal, dialog);
    form.addRow(&buttonBox);
    QObject::connect(&buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), dialog, SLOT(accept()));
    QObject::connect(&buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), dialog, SLOT(reject()));

    dialog->exec();
}

void MainWindow::updateValues(const QString & text)
{
    name->setText(text);
    time->setText(text);
    number->setText(text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and detailed answer.
But it seems like it is not possible to do it "inside" the function, so I will change my Project according to your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks to you. Let me know if you need additional details or even if you finally solved the problem.

Comment: I solved the problem.
I did not make it as big as your example, because this Form is part of a very big project and I did not want to change to much stuff around.
So I just added a global QLineEdit "Path" which I can access from every function in the class, and then I added a Pushbutton + Slot to runt he OpenFile Dialog and write the result in the LineEdit
But Thanks again for the idea

Comment: @NIoSaT Great! :) Happy coding!